# bash with "bad substitution" on windows bash

Tags: windows, bash, parameters, sh, substitution

I try to build the optiboot bootloader. This working with a few errors and I try to solve them. I guess optiboot is made to build on linux system.
So I installed https://sourceforge.net/projects/win-bash/files/shell-complete/latest/ and add its path to PATH variable.

But the bash/sh script was still comming back with "bad substitution"

The generated bash script look like the following. I added already the first line with #!/bin/bash but it gave not success.

```
#!/bin/bash
# 1 "baudcheck.c"
# 1 "C:\\Users\\trivalik\\Downloads\\arduino-1.8.0    \\hardware\\anet\\avr\\bootloaders\\atmega//"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "baudcheck.c"
# 24 "baudcheck.c"
bpsx=115200
bps=${bpsx/L/}
bps=${bps/U/}
fcpux=16000000L
fcpu=${fcpux/L/}
fcpu=${fcpu/U/}

echo $bpsx
echo $bps
```

when I execute this on operating system Windows 10 with "bash baudcheck.tmp.sh" I get:

```
115200

baudcheck.tmp.sh: ${bpsx/L/}: bad substitution
baudcheck.tmp.sh: ${bps/U/}: bad substitution
baudcheck.tmp.sh: ${fcpux/L/}: bad substitution
baudcheck.tmp.sh: ${fcpu/U/}: bad substitution
```

The main question is, what is on parameter substitiution on Windows different?
Or is it complete disabled?

All the bash tips here could me not help.

Edit:

Solution seems to be that the bash from win-bash is very very old.
The Version returns:

```
bash$ echo $BASH_VERSION
win-bash_0.8.5(0)
```

Instead I used now the bash from git for Windows https://git-for-windows.github.io/

this bash version is not the newest but higher:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.3.42(5)-release
```

Does anybody know a higher bash Version for Windows?

Comment: The version 0.8.5 has nothing to do with the underlying version of `bash` implemented by `win-bash`.

Comment: I was guessing also so, but why then the win-bash not working?

Comment: Frankly, it doesn't sound like it's worth worrying about. `win-bash` hasn't been updated in 6 years, and 4.3 is a very recent version of `bash` (4.4 was only release in the last few months).

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, standard `sh` parameter expansions might suffice. For example, `${bpsx%[LU]}` produces `$bpsx` with any `L` or `U` suffix trimmed off. Your example only shows an `L` suffix so it's unclear what exactly you are trying to trim off.

Comment: Other than that, the Bash which ships with the Windows port of Git is probably the best supported and maintained these days, unless of course you come to your senses and get rid of Windows entirely.